# Python with Mysql - pdf file insertion during runtime

Tags: python, mysql

I have a script that stores results in pdf format in a particular folder. I want to create a mysql database ( which is successful with the below code ), and populate the pdf results to it. what would be the best way , storing the file as such , or as reference to the location. The file size would be around 2MB. Could someone help in explaining the same with some working examples. I am new to both python and mysql.Thanks in advance. 
To clarify more : I tried using LOAD DATA INFILE and the BLOB type for the result file column , but it dosent seem to work .I am using pymysql api module to connect to the database.Below code is to connect to the database and is successful.

```
import pymsql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='hostname', port=3306, user='root', passwd='abcdef', db='mydb')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM userlogin")
for r in cur.fetchall():
   print(r)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: You are asking two questions in one post, and you haven't really explained what you need by providing a specific example and some code that you have written that didn't work. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: edited with more specific details

Comment: Is your question 'how do I get data from the mysql database using pymysql?` or 'how do I write data to a pdf file?`If you make your question clear and specific (that is, choose one problem to work on at a time) you will get better answers.

Comment: my question is how to write pdf file to database . if that is not efficient way , then how do i create reference to that file and store that path in db using python.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be close to getting mysql to store strings for you (user names), your best bet is to just stick with what you did there and store the file path just as you stored the strings in your `userlogin` table (but in a different table with a foreign key to `userlogin`). It will probably be the most efficient approach in the long run anyway, especially if you store important metadata along with the file path (like keywords or even complete n-gram sets)... now you're talking about a file indexing system like Google Desktop or Xapian... just so you know what you're up against if you want to do this the "best" way.